# Django: Test content of email sent

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm sending out an email to users with a generated link, and I wanna write a test that verifies whether the link is correct, but I can't find a way to get the content of the email inside the test.

Is there a way to do that?

If it helps at all, this is how I'm sending the email:

```
content = template.render(Context({'my_link': my_link}))
subject = _('Email with link')
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject,
                             from_email='MyWebsite Team <mywebsite@mywebsite.com>',
                             to=[user.email, ])
msg.attach_alternative(content, 'text/html')
msg.send()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs have [an entire section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#email-services) on testing emails.

```
self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].subject, 'Email with link')
```